# Wordpress Multi Site (Networking enabled)

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I want to programatically create a Blog/Site in Wordpress Muti site (Networking enabled wordpres). Is there any API to do that? If Not, Can I directly insert the data into the data base?

I want to create a wordpress site based on one of my custom registration forms from a php page. Any Help/Links to the documentation will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for sub directory installs:

```
global $current_site;
wpmu_create_blog( $current_site->domain, $current_site->path . 'mysite/', 'My Site', 1 );
```

and this should work for sub domain installs:

```
global $current_site, $base;
wpmu_create_blog( 'mysite.mydomain.com', $base, 'My Site', 1 );
```

if you need to add a blog with and a user at the same time, check out the code in /wp-admin/ms-edit.php around where it says 'case 'addblog':' on line 139. THere is code to sanitze the domain, following there is code to add a new user from an email.

Comment: hello, any response on this. did it help?

Comment: wpmu_create_blog adds all the information to the database ( I can query and see). But the WP dashboard is not showing the blog. I am still working on it. Direction you gave me is what I wanted. Thank you. By any chance, do you know how many blogs are recommended on one wordpress/mysql installation?

Comment: you can have many thousands of blogs on one install. there really is no limit if you enable caching and set the server or servers up properly. WP is built to scale.